# How can position the bottom footer?

Tags: html, css

I have this site:

[link](http://dg-design.ch/bagel/?page_id=12)

As you can see footer is positioned at the top and I want the bottom,
I put a picture more clearly understand what they want to do

[image]

**CODE HTML:**

```
<footer class="content-info" role="contentinfo">
  <div class="container-fluid no-padding">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-4 col-address">
        <div class="contact">
          <div class="title-footer">
            <p class="title-footer">CONTACT</p>
          </div>
        <div class="content-footer">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div class="img-footer">
              <img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/address-footer.png">
              </div>
              <div class="details-footer">
              <span>Rue de Marche 3, 1204 Geneva</span>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="img-footer">
              <img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/email-footer.png">
              </div>
              <div class="details-footer">
              <span>info@bagelhousecafe.ch</span>
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="img-footer">
              <img class="phone-footer" src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/telephone-footer.png">
              </div>
              <div class="details-footer">
              <span>+41 79 132 80 85</span>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-center ">
        <div class="title-footer">
          <p class="title-footer">FOLLOW US</p>
        </div>
        <div class="content-footer">
          <ul class="follow">
            <li>
              <div class="img-footer">
                <img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/facebook-footer.png">
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="img-footer">
                <img src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/twitter-footer.png">
              </div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="img-footer">
                <img class="phone-footer" src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/themes/wp_bagel/assets/img/instagram-footer.png">
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="copyright">
          <p>Copyright © 2016 - 2016 Bagel House Cafe</p>
          <p>All rights reserved</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 newsletter">
        <div class="title-footer">
          <p class="title-footer">NEWSLETTER</p>
        </div>
        <div class="news-input">
          <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/plugins/email-newsletter/widget/widget.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-content/plugins/email-newsletter/widget/widget.css">
<div>
  <div class="eemail_caption">
    Sign up for our email newsletters  </div>
  <div class="eemail_msg">
    <span id="eemail_msg"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="eemail_textbox">
    <input class="eemail_textbox_class" name="eemail_txt_email" id="eemail_txt_email" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13) eemail_submit_ajax('http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php')" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Enter email';" onfocus="if(this.value=='Enter email') this.value='';" value="Enter email" maxlength="150" type="text">
  </div>
  <div class="eemail_button">
    <input class="eemail_textbox_button" name="eemail_txt_Button" id="eemail_txt_Button" onclick="return eemail_submit_ajax('http://dg-design.ch/bagel/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php')" value="Submit" type="button">
  </div>
</div>          <p class="copyright dg">Website by DGdesign</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Can you please tell me which is why it is so high pozitioneaa?
Can I arrange it in CSS?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: here is an example with bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

Comment: your main div with container-fluid class before footer has height of just 1px

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position:absolute` causes 1 px height to your `.wrapper .content` which is creating all the fuss. Just replace it with `position: static` or `position: relative`. It solves the issue.

```
.wrapper .content {
    position: absolute;// this on line number 6739 of your css
    margin:0;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @Marius you can also just simply remove the position: absolute; from `.wrapper .content` and it solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

if you want it fixed in position

```
footer {
    background: #7a1418;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

but it would seem there is more going on there

Answer (score 0):

if you want it to sitck in the botoom of the screen all time you must use

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

but if you want your footer in the end of use this :

```
<body>

<div class='wrap'>
site content
</div>

<footer>
your footer
</footer>

</body>
```

and the css is:

```
.wrap{width:100%;min-height: 100%;height: auto !important;height: 100%;margin: 0 auto 10%;}

footer{bottom:0px;display:block;width:100%;height:auto;}
```

in margin: 0 auto 10%; you can change 10% to set the height of your footer

Answer (score -1):

Make a DIV with ID footer and
than add footer to DIV.

Link your CSS and in css add this:

```
footer {
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
}
```

And also you must add some content in middle so you would see diffrence

Comment: I do not undestand why I got voted down. Code and explanation was correct

Comment: I think because you have added `position:fixed` to the footer, as it will fix the footer to bottom of the page and will also cover the page with footer at the bottom. And on that the user will always see the footer on screen in-spite of scrolling. Just improve your answer and you may also get an upvote.